# Unable to Login to My App Using Facebook Login

Tags: facebook

Our is a very old app and the developers who did the Facebook login integration are no longer working with us. So we can’t get into our Facebook Developer account because no one in the team has access.

Can we just create a new Facebook Developer account and update our integration ID to match the new account ?

Are there any risks? One thing I’m wondering about is if we do make this change if all the users who have previously registered via Facebook login need to register with us again because it is a new ID. But on the other hand, it might work since it is still the same App Id and the same Facebook user account.

Please help.

Comment: If you don't have access to the app dashboard via any old developer account, then you won't be able to add a new one.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, So can we upgrade the app with the new facebook developer account and will the old users will have to register again using their facebook credentials ?

Comment: If you create a new app id, then all your users will get new app-scoped user ids, meaning you won't be able to recognize them as already existing users any more. (Unless you used something else besides the user id for that, like f.e. their email - but not all Facebook user _have_ an email set in their profile, or they might have changed it since the created an account on your site.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, CBroe. But if the email is set in their profile, then they will be able to login into our app using their email Facebook credential and they need not register again.

Comment: _If_ your app is actually using the email address as identifying criterion, and not the app-scoped user ID.